# Back to previous page with browser back button, OK - back with plain JavaScript, Not OK

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

In my website I have a products page and when you click on a product, it goes to the details of the product.

The link of the product page is: http://www.dummyurl.com/Index.html#/category/1/Foam?price=13.13-26.25&color=Green

The link of the product detail page is: http://www.dummyurl.com/Index.html#/products/2450-Kunda/5036702024506?price=13.13-26.25&color=Green

When I click on the back button of the browser I will be rejected to the product page with the link: http://www.dummyurl.com/Index.html#/category/1/Foam?price=13.13-26.25&color=Green

But I want also a html button on the product detail page.
Behind the button their is plain Javascript with the code: $window.history.back();

When I click the back button, I will be rejected to the following url:http://www.dummyurl.com/Index.html
This is the start url when I launch my website and not the url where I came from.

It looks like the routing in AngularJS sends me to the default url.

Anybody got an idea to fix this?

Comment: This might help you. have a look at it http://stackoverflow.com/a/14070562/2415086

Comment: Thanks Techno Savvy, that solution worked out for me!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement history.back() in angular.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070285/how-to-implement-history-back-in-angular-js)