# Back and Forward between controllers

Tags: angularjs

I'm having an issue developping my website in AngularJS during the implementation of the back and forward buttons.

```
// app.js
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
  .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/Page1', {
          templateUrl: 'partial/view1.html', controller: Ctrl1})
      .when('/Page2', {
          templateUrl: 'partial/view2.html', controller: Ctrl2})
      .otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/Page1'});
}]);
```

When I navigate from page 1 to page 2 I can't go back even using the following directive :

```
// app.js
app.directive('backButton', function(){
    return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                  element.bind('click', goBack);

                  function goBack() {
                     history.back();
                     scope.$apply();
                  }
            }
    }
});
```

-

```
<!-- view1.html / view2.html -->
<i class="fa fa-chevron-left" back-button></i>
```

Yet it works when I back on the same view.
Is there a solution ?

Thanks

Edit:
$window doesn't help either since I've tried changing my directive as such :

```
// app.js
app.directive('backButton', ['$window', function($window) {
    return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                  element.bind('click', goBack);

                  function goBack() {
                     $window.history.back();
                     scope.$apply();
                  }
            }
    }
});
```

and got the same behavior.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement history.back() in angular.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070285/how-to-implement-history-back-in-angular-js)

Comment: Actually I tried everything posted on the topic you linked but as I explained, it doesn't work between view with different controllers.

Comment: Did you try the `$window` service: `$window.history.back();`?

Comment: Yes, same behavior as the rest.

Answer (score 0):

As Davin said in his comment, you have to use `$window.history.back();` from the `$window` service. Don't forget to declare it as a dependency of your directive as such

```
directive('directiveName', ['$window', function($window) {
    ...
  }])
```

EDIT: the full working directive with no typo

```
app.directive('backButton', ['$window', function($window) {
    return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element) {
                  element.bind('click', function() {
                     $window.history.back();
                  });
            }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: As I answered his comment, $window.history.back() has the same behavior than history.back() in my case. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Well you're missing a square bracket in your directive so that's probably why it's not working. I fixed your typo and tried out the directive exactly as you wrote it and it works just fine. Note: I'm using ui-router instead of ng-route but it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Actually there wasn't a missing bracket in my code, it's a mistake I made only on Stack Overflow (sorry guyz)

I tested changing from ng-route to ui-router and that was it !
Thank you.

Comment: mmmh that is strange though, it should still work with ng-route (maybe  you configured that wrong?). Anyway, I think ui-router is the better option.

Comment: Actually after I really tested it, It doesn't work properly even changing to ui-routes. I can forward and back but only on the same page not from one page to another keeping the arguments as they were.