# $window.history.back does not work in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, browser-history

I am borrowing an example here to implement Back button:

[How to implement history.back() in angular.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070285/how-to-implement-history-back-in-angular-js)

The way I did it was to create a function `back()`:

http://jsfiddle.net/qhoc/WaRKv/110/

```
app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', '$window', '$location', function($scope, $window, $location) {

  $scope.log = function() {
    console.log($location.path());
  };

  $scope.back = function() {
    $window.history.back();
    console.log($location.path());
  };

}]);
```

But it doesn't work. The event is hit but the location output in console log doesn't change.

Please help

**UPDATE 12/28:**

I ran http://jsfiddle.net/WaRKv/111/ and did the following:

1. Click Link 1 once
2. Click Link 2 once
3. Then finally click Back once.

Please see below screenshot. It doesn't work still as the Back button should log Link 1 but it kept showing Link 2.

[image]

Comment: You code works, it just seems like it's not going back because it's loaded in an iframe in jsfiddle. Try it full screen here:
http://jsfiddle.net/qhoc/WaRKv/110/embedded/result/

Comment: I just tried that link. Still dont work for me in both Safari and Chrome. The back button kept output the existing url

Answer (score 1):

You have to listen for the  $locationChangeSuccess Event before logging to the console.

```
 $scope.$on("$locationChangeSuccess",function(event,newUrl, oldUrl) {
        console.log("location: "+$location.path());
    });
```

You log the location before it is finished changing.

See:

http://jsfiddle.net/WaRKv/111/

Unfortunately somehow the event is revieved twice, I dont know why and the back button doesnt work as well :/ maybe jsfiddle problems

Comment: It doesn't work from what I saw. Please see my update with screenshot