# How to show the back button only if it leads to the same single-page-application in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browser-history, referrer

I know how to implement back button in AngularJS: [How to implement history.back() in angular.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070285/how-to-implement-history-back-in-angular-js)

And I want to display it only when **BACK** would lead me to the same application:

```
<a ng-click="back()" ng-show="isBackAvailable()">BACK</a>
```

I would like **BACK** to be hidden if it would lead to some other page.

My current implementation looks like this:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $window) {
  var acceptableReferrers = ["http://127.0.0.1:9000/"];

  $rootScope.back = function() {
    $window.history.back();
  }

  $rootScope.isBackAvailable = function() {
    var result = _.contains(acceptableReferrers, document.referrer);
    console.log(result)
    return result;
  }
});
```

**This does not work.**

When I paste `http://127.0.0.1:9000/` into the browser bar the `document.referrer` is `""` (empty string). However if I do this the following way:
`<a href="http://127.0.0.1:9000/#/search">now referrer will be correct</a>`

---

Please advise.

Comment: You could try to use `$location.absUrl()` and then check if the URL contains any of the acceptable referrers

Comment: @callmekatootie - ```$location.absUrl()``` tried using it but doesn't work for me :(

Comment: You mean it does not return anything?

Comment: Sorry for not being more precise. It always return the current URL I'm in. It doesn't work for me in a sense that it doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

`document.referrer` returns the entire url of the previous page, so if you want your function to work you can't check that it matches exactly.

Maybe try something less specific like checking `document.referrer` for the same hostname:

```
$rootScope.isBackAvailable = function() {
  var result = _.contains(document.referrer, window.location.hostname);
  console.log(result)
  return result;
};
```

Comment: document.referrer is going to be empty any time a user pastes a url into the address bar. That's what's failing, according to the question. I don't think this will help with that.

Comment: It's a single-page-application and ```document.referrer``` is always ```http://127.0.0.1:9000/"```  regardless my location and how many clicks in the app I've made.

Answer (score 1):

I've had to solve the same problem in an AngularJS app and I used the `$window.history.length` to make the determination.  When the app initially loads, I save the initial history length in a variable.  When the Back button is clicked I compare the current history length with the initial.  If my current history is larger, I know that I can go back at least one page to my original starting point.  The current index will never be smaller than the initial because its impossible to navigate "back" to a lower index and stay in the app.

This would look something like the following:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $window) {
  var historyLength = $window.history.length;

  $rootScope.back = function() {
    $window.history.back();
  }

  $rootScope.isBackAvailable = function() {
    return $window.history.length > historyLength;
  }
});
```