# Angularjs history in hashbang mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using hashbang mode navigation. I have a "cancel/go back" button on the item detail page which takes me  back to the item results page, I use window.history.back() to achieve this. This works fine when users come to item details page from the  results page.

But if I land directly on the item detail page and click cancel, window.history.back() takes me to whatever page was on the browser's history. Instead I want it to go to #/home . I tried checking document.referrer but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the $location service of Angular. This will probably fix your problem.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

To go back in history you should have a look into this topic: [How to implement history.back() in angular.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070285/how-to-implement-history-back-in-angular-js)

Answer (score 0):

You may use [$locationProvider](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/docs/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider) and [$location](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/docs/guide/$location).

OnClick of the back button, you need to check [$location.state()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#state) and use [$location.path()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#path) to drive the user in the back state you prefer.

Comment: I cannot use html5mode because of IE9 users. $location.state() is only supported in html5 browsers as per docs