# History in angularjs routing doesn't work

Tags: angularjs

i am coding an angular app i already created my app routing

```
AdminDashboard.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){    
    $routeProvider
        .when('/',{
            templateUrl: '../dashboard/administration/dashboard.html',
            controller : 'Dashboard'}
            )
            //Students Routes
        .when('/Students', {
            templateUrl : '../dashboard/administration/students/students.html',
            controller: 'ShowStudentsController'}
             )
        .when('/Students/:studentId/edit',{
            templateUrl : '../dashboard/administration/students/modals/edit.html',
            controller: 'EditStudentsController'
        })
        .when('/Students/create',{
            templateUrl : '../dashboard/administration/students/modals/create.html',
            controller: 'CreateStudentsController'
        });
        }]);
```

and the history wasn't working i did a research on Anuglar API 
and i found that i've to add.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

and then the browser back button was working and getting to the previous route but the template won't render.
Please help me. And i hope my question is clear.

Comment: Here is a post on Angular Back button 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070285/how-to-implement-history-back-in-angular-js

Comment: The console is always saying the angular.map files are missing?

Comment: Thanks Paul, thats one solution. but how can i handle the browser back button

Comment: what's happening with the browser back button now? ANy errors?

Comment: Without adding the locationProvider it's not returning to the previous page but the template of the actual page is working normally, but when adding the locationProvider the history mapping is working but no template rendering and the only errors that are showing are the missing map files and that was the case even before adding the locationProvider.

Comment: @Cine get your map files  http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.12/

Comment: Done, but sadly nothing changed except there is no map errors now.

Comment: Never seen this issue and you don't need `html5mode` either for routing to work ( assuming using hash). SOmething else is wrong in your app

Comment: The result of my route url is somthing like this /Administration#/Students
shouldn't be like this /Administration/#/Students?

Comment: I really don't know what might be wrong since the console is clear what you suggest me to do @charlietfl?

Comment: WHat are you using for href?

Comment: It works now indeed it was an error in href ^^ Thanks for help @charlietfl really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(sorry, my rep is too low to add this as a comment but...)

I had a similar weird problem with routing not working earlier and it turned out to be a stray # link from the basic page design. I'm sure there's a perfectly good reason for that, but clicking on this # link would break all browser navigation for the remainder of the session.

Replacing those # hrefs with #/ prevented the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks, for bringing me joy ^^ really appreciate it. it worked just fine now

Comment: You're welcome, I ended up implementing all sorts of providers and services and whatnot until I finally realized what was actually causing the problem. Glad to have saved you something of that aggravation :)