# AngularJS: Get previous url (path) from page

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a question: When I'm in a page I want return to previous page. I use the `$routeProvider`. How can I read the previous url?

I try to use this code in my controller but doesn't work...

```
angular.module.controller('myController', 
  function($scope, $routeParams, $http, $location, $rootScope) {

    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", 
      function (event, current, previous, rejection) {

        console.log(previous);
        $location.path('PREVIOUS PATH');

    });
 });
```

How can I read the previous path? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I am not fully sure, what you want to achieve. So I would suggest, check this before you go your own way:

[How to implement history.back() in angular.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14070285/1679310)

But, in case, you want to know how to keep the last state with angular and UI-Router, we can do it with a service. There is some naive implementation tracking just last state (not challenging the history.back())

Check the [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/FF9G8dAbBSXcKMOmnp4G?p=preview)

Service definition:

```
.factory('PreviousState', ['$rootScope', '$state',
  function ($rootScope, $state) {

    var lastHref = "/home",
        lastStateName = "home", 
        lastParams = {}; 

    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function (event, toState, toParams
                                                       , fromState, fromParams) {
      lastStateName = fromState.name;
      lastParams = fromParams;
      lastHref = $state.href(lastStateName, lastParams)  
    })

    return {
      getLastHref: function (){ return lastHref ; },
      goToLastState: function (){ return $state.go(lastStateName, lastParams); },
    }

}])
```

So we just do listen the [$stateChangeSuccess](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state#events_$statechangesuccess) and keep the track of last `state` **name** and its **`$stateParams`**.

We can inject our service to all scopes:

```
.run(['$rootScope', 'PreviousState',
  function ($rootScope, PreviousState) {
    $rootScope.PreviousState = PreviousState;
}])
```

And we can use it as a click or href:

```
<button ng-click="PreviousState.goToLastState()">go back</button>
<a ng-href="#{{PreviousState.getLastHref()}}" > go to last href</a>
```

Check that in [action here](http://plnkr.co/edit/FF9G8dAbBSXcKMOmnp4G?p=preview)

Comment: I resolved with similar solution...I used $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function (evt, absNewUrl, absOldUrl) and so I can take the absOldUrl...Thanks!