# Browser back button click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

Am new to AngularJs, I want to write a custom function when user clicks browser back button.

This is my function in my controller. It should invoke when user clicks browser back button.

```
$scope.backBrnClick = function(){
         var userId=1;
         $rootScope['backup']['sesionId']=null;
    };
```

How can I achieve this function in Angular JS.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070285/how-to-implement-history-back-in-angular-js

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I want to invoke my function when click browser back button. In those examples all related ng-click event.