# Go back to previous page without reloading

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

I have a website by `mean-stack`.

I want to add a web page `https://localhost:3000/A`. This page contains a textarea where people could write a text, it also contains a button `go forward to Page B`. Thus clicking on the button leads to `https://localhost:3000/B`. `Page B` prints the text (which can not be edited) that was written in `Page A`. It also contains a button `go back to Page A`, which leads back to `Page A`.

When we click on `go back to Page A`, I don't want the browser to reload `https://localhost:3000/A` (ie, execute all the functions in `resolve`) ; I just want to go back to the previous state of `Page A` (with previous text) right before going to `Page B`.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

**PS:** `Page A` and `Page B` have different controllers. Additionally, for some reasons I can **NOT** enable `html5mode` in my website.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('A', {
        url: '/A',
        templateUrl: 'A.html',
        controller: 'ACtrl'
    }
    .state('B', {
        url: '/B',
        templateUrl: 'B.html',
        controller: 'BCtrl'
    }
```

**Edit 1:** I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23351154/702977). The `back` button did lead to previous page, which was however **reloaded**, that's not what I want.

Comment: There shouldn't be two URLs/states for these two "pages". It makes no sense, for example, to be able to navigate to B without going to A before. Just use ng-if to hide A and show B (or vice versa), in a single router state.

Comment: @JBNizet I see what you mean... Do you have any idea about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48126131/hide-a-monaco-editor)?