# Cannot hide a Monaco Editor

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, monaco-editor

I have a Monaco Editor in my page. Now, I need to hide/show it from time to time. But I realise that it does not work well (see the screenshot below) with `ng-show`, `ng-hide` or `ng-if`. Does anyone have a solution?

https://jsbin.com/mepupagisi/4/edit?html,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-show="true">
        <div id="container"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://www.matrixlead.com/monaco-editor/min/vs/loader.js"></script>
    <script>
        require.config({ paths: { 'vs': 'https://www.matrixlead.com/monaco-editor/min/vs' }})

        require(["vs/editor/editor.main"], function () {
          var editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
            value: 'function x() {\n\tconsole.log("Hello world!");\n}',
            language: 'javascript',
            minimap: { enabled: false },
            scrollBeyondLastLine: false
          });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit 1:** I still see a thin line:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work well"?

Comment: @TsvetanGanev Don't you see it is not completely hidden?

Comment: There is no such thing as "incompletely hidden". `ng-show` and `ng-hide` just toggle the `display: none` CSS property while `ng-if` removes the elements from the DOM completely.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use AngularJS directives, you first have to declare the scope of your application by adding the `ng-app` attribute to a container element. For example:

```
<body ng-app>
  <div ng-hide="true">
    Will be hidden
  </div>
</body>
```

Now you can use all of the built-in AngularJS directives inside the body tag.

Here is a working [JSBin demo](https://jsbin.com/tatanubisu/1/edit?html,output). See how the `ng-hide=true` hides the Monaco editor. Remove that directive or change it to `ng-hide=false` to see it shown again.

Comment: I added a JSBin demo.

Comment: I see... In my real code, I use `flexbox` which may causes trouble, I will show a full non-working example...

Comment: This has nothing to do with AngularJS and the original problem.